# History of 6 Teveis

Tags: jewish-date-series, history, calendar

****Looking for answers as to what happened in Jewish history on this date. It can include both positive and negative occurrences. It can also include birthdays or Yarzheits of well known personalities that happened on this date.**

**Please cite / link your sources, if possible.**

**All interesting answers will be up voted.**

***Best answer will be accepted.*****

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of links:

My blog, which I pull just a small dose of what happened from different sources: http://jewishalmanac.wordpress.com

Other sources I like:

For Jewish calendar-

http://www.chabad.org/calendar/default_cdo/jewish/Jewish-Calendar.htm

For Yahrzeits: http://chinuch.org/AdarII.php

For secular calendar: http://thisdayinjewishhistory.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that 10 Tevet may be associated with the holiday widely celebrated on 25 December (of course, it was more of a callamity for the Jewish people).

Considering the accuracy of our (and their) typical calendar calculations, 6 Tevet is as likely a date as any.

Comment: Just to clarify, R'Jeremy: You have no reason to think the sixth of _Teves_ is the date on which Jesus was born: you're merely saying it's as likely a date as any other on the calendar? In other words, this answer is, as far as you know, as appropriate for _any_ "History of [date]" question as it is for this one?

Comment: well, not *just* as likely. I assume that 6 Teves never coincides with July 4, but does occasionally coincide with Dec 25.
I really should have saide "6 Teves is as likely as any other overlapping date"

Answer (score 0):

Yarzheit of R' Yechezkel Shraga Halberstam of Shiniva ben R' Chaim of Sanz, author of Divrei Yechezkel and also the Yarzheit of R' Yaakov Reischer, author of Chok Yaakov and Shvus Yaakov